# What is the complete file header for an XLS spreadsheet?

Tags: header, hex, spreadsheet, header-files, xls

Using this [website](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) on file signatures I have found the beginning of the file header for an XLS spreadsheet:

"09 08 10 00 00 06 05 00"

I was wondering if there was any further information you can glean from the header such as Author etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not from headers per se: an XLS file is an OLE document. To extract the autor etc, you need to be able to read the SummaryInformation and DocumentSummaryInformation streams from within that file.